# Update multiple images in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I'm facing some issue regarding update multiple images in PHP.
actually, I have 8 buttons for 8 images for adding and updating images & 8 separate columns in MySQL Database, so when I update images separately it either update all 8 columns value, even if I select only image1 & image2 then too it will update all columns & image3 to image7 will contain empty values in database

> If I use `&&` 'AND' operator

or it does not update any values of column images (image, image1, image2,.... image7)

> If I use `||` 'OR' operator

But what exactly I want is if I want to update any of the images from image1 - image8 only that image should get updated & rest of the values in the database should remain the same as the previous values, the values in images column is the name of the images.

```
if(empty($image) && empty($image1) && empty($image2) && empty($image3) && empty($image4) && empty($image5) && empty($image6) && empty($image7) ){

        $UpdateSql = "UPDATE car SET mobile='$mobile' WHERE id=$id";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateSql);

    }else{

        $UpdateSql = "UPDATE car_list SET mobile='$mobile', image='$image', image1='$image1',image2= '$image2', image3='$image3',image4='$image4',image5='$image5', image6='$image6',image7='$image7' WHERE id=$id";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $UpdateSql);

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might I suggest you have made a database design error here. The images should be in a seperate table linked to `car_list` using its id

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Actually storing the Mobile numbers like that is also a bad idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly could you please elaborate it like with one example that how it can be updated?

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually for asking query at stack overflow i just wrote sample code but i had provided the security :)

Comment: Well its very difficult debugging code that does not really exists, so I wont bother

Comment: Where's the part where you use CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a SQL query based on what image variables have values. For example:

```
$mobile = "someMobileNo";
$id = 1234;

$image = "";
$image1 = "";
$image2 = "some.png";
$image3 = "";
$image4 = "";
$image5 = "someOther.png";
$image6 = "yetAnother.png";
$image7 = "";

$imageVars = array($image, $image1, $image2, $image3, $image4, $image5, $image6, $image7,);

$updateImages = "";

for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i ++){
    if(!empty($imageVars[$i])){
        //the image variable has a value, add it to the UPDATE query
        $imageNum = (string)$i; //cast index as string
        if($imageNum == "0"){
            //first image does not have a number
            $imageNum = "";
        }
        $updateImages .= ",image" . $imageNum . "='" . $imageVars[$i] . "'";
    }
}

$UpdateSql = "UPDATE car_list SET mobile='$mobile'" . $updateImages . " WHERE id=$id";

echo $UpdateSql;


//OUTPUT:
//    UPDATE car_list SET mobile='someMobileNo',image2='some.png',image5='someOther.png',image6='yetAnother.png' WHERE id=1234
```